# Expressionengine migration module

Tags: migration, feature-request

I'm a newbie in expression engine and would like to know if there is a module, app, plugin or script that allows for one to move not only the site but addonn settings from local > staging > production.

I have used drupal 7 and they have a features module where dependencies for specific modules can be set and moved from local > staging and production without having to setup on the different environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find a thing called [MasterConfig](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) by FocusLabs is what you need.  You can read more about it and how to use it in this useful posting by Patrick Pohler -“[ExpressionEngine multiple environments with Master Config](http://www.patpohler.com/expressionengine-multiple-environments/)”

I’ve not used it, but general feedback on the EE Slack suggests that many do, and find it useful, but that configuration for multiple platforms can be a bit of challenge.

HTH

Comment: will give this a try